# Load data from map field ind Cloud Firestore using FirebaseFirestoreSwift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Been loosing a lot of sleep over this. Just started to program again and can't wrap my head around this one.

I'm trying to map my documents into "Shop" objects, but how would you retrieve the hours field and convert it into a [String:Any].

Error: Type 'Shop' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
Error: Type 'Shop' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Shop.swift

```
struct Shop: Codable, Identifiable {
  @DocumentID var id: String?

  var image: String
  var name: String
  var adress: [String:String]?
  var openingHours: [[String: Any]] // Gives the error above
}
```

ShopRepository.swift

```
class ShopRepository: ObservableObject {
  let database = Firestore.firestore()
  @Published var shops = [Shop]()

  init() {
    loadData()
  }

  func loadData() {
    database.collection("shops").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
            self.shops = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                do {
                    print(document.data())
                    return try document.data(as: Shop.self)
                }
                catch { print(error) }
                
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: The map field?  I don't see it anywhere in your code.

Comment: @ElTomato sorry, what I ment was the hours field Which is of type map

Comment: Is `Codable` a mandatory protocol for this structure? If you drop it, this is all very straightforward. The problem is that `Codable` objects cannot contain `Any` types. And unfortunately, the `hours` array contains maps with varying value types which requires the use of `Any`. Must this structure be encodable?

Comment: @bsod Yes unfortunately, FirebaseFirestoreSwift requires that model is Codable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must take this approach then you have a few options. However, when working with Firestore in Swift, there is no requirement that you use `Codable`—this approach is just one way to parse Firestore data into native Swift objects. The only upside to this approach is that your objects are now encodable. But do you need these objects to be encodable? Or do you prefer this approach for the little amount of code needed to parse data into objects? The tradeoff is the very problem you have, that you can't make use of `[String: Any]` types which are prevalent in the Firestore API.

Before you go down this road, know that you can just as easily ditch `Codable` and map the documents using an initializer that takes a `[String: Any]` dictionary. That said, to stick with this approach, you have to get rid of the `[String: Any]` dictionary because `Codable` cannot work with type `Any`, it must be given concrete, primitive Swift types.

```
struct Shop: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    
    var image: String
    var name: String
    var adress: [String:String]?
    var openingHours: [[String: String]]
}
```

One option is to convert all of the fields in the hours dictionaries to strings. This would solve your problem but `closed` would be the string `"false"` (not the boolean) and so would the other two integer properties. To me this is an ugly workaround.

```
struct Shop: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    
    var image: String
    var name: String
    var adress: [String:String]?
    var openingHours: [Hours]
}

struct Hours: Codable {
    let closed: Bool
    let closesAt: Int
    let day: String
    let opensAt: Int
}
```

Another option is to make `openingHours` its own structure.

```
struct Shop {
    let id: String
    let image: String
    let name: String
    var address: [String: String]?
    let openingHours: [[String: Any]]
    
    init?(data: [String: Any]?) {
        guard let data = data,
              let id = data["id"] as? String,
              let image = data["image"] as? String,
              let name = data["name"] as? String,
              let openingHours = data["openingHours"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
            return nil
        }
        let address = data["address"] as? [String: String]
        
        self.id = id
        self.image = image
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.openingHours = openingHours
    }
}
```

And then you can just ditch `Codable` entirely and take your Firestore dictionary and plug it into a custom initializer. Notice that I've made `address` an optional so that even if there is no address, a structure will still be made. However, if any of the other properties are missing then the structure will not be made. This is because the initializer is failable, as denoted by the `?` after `init`, which simply means that it can fail and return `nil` if it doesn't meet your custom conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good explanations, all options could fix the problem. I went with the last one and ditched the Codable :)